# can .NET application ask the MS-Windows system to unblock a DRM protected PDF file so it can decode it?

Tags: .net, pdf, adobe, password-protection, drm

I know some programming framework offer DRM management. I ask if .NET technology is suitable to unblock a DRM protected PDF file (Adobe DRM first of all) so that the application can open and read it (it can parse the file, it just wants the file unblocked).

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about downloading a file and that its blocked, this is stored in an alternate data stream attached to the file in question with a name of "Zone.Identifier".

For instance, if you downloaded test.pdf, then test.pdf:Zone.Identifier will exist. You can see this file by launching notepad from the command line with "notepad test.pdf:Zone.Identifier".

Another tool to see these files is [ADSSpy](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/files/adsspy.php).

Another good resource talking about it http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml

Comment: I am talking about creating a .Net application and making it able to display DRM protected PDF files that the users legally purchased on an authorized WindowsPC. Is the unblocking/decrypting/decoding task performed by the system or .Net classes? Or Should I buy some Adobe (or the like) license?

Comment: Ah, that would probably be Adobe then, or whichever tool you use for dealing with the PDF's.